# What does the notation $1_\Omega(x)$ mean?

Tags: notation

An author in a paper suggests that a binary function f(x) can be expressed as

$f(x) = 1_\Omega(x)$

where $f(x) \in \{0,1\}$ for all $ x \in R^2$

$\Omega$ is an arbitrary bounded measurable subset of $R^2$

What does he mean when he expresses $f(x)$  as $1_\Omega(x)$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called [Indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function); it means that $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in \Omega$, and $f(x) = 0$ if $x \notin \Omega$.

Comment: This seems to make sense, why has this been voted down ?

Comment: Now the link works.

Comment: (1) Sometimes also called the *characteristic function*.

Comment: (2) Sometimes other notation is used: $\chi_\Omega$ for example, or the Knuth/Arrow notation $[\Omega]$

Comment: (3) In category theory, you may see $1_\Omega$ meaning the identity function on $\Omega$.