# Bold 1 with subscripts - How should this be read?

Tags: notation

I am struggling to understand the notation i.e. what does the bold 1 refer to?

$\mathbf{1}_{A\cap B}(x)=\mathbf{1}_{A}(x)\times\mathbf{1}_{B}(x)$

Comment: it's the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42980/42969

Answer (score 1):

It's presumably the indicator function
\begin{align*}
{\bf 1}_S(x) &= \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x\in S$}; \\
0 & \text{if $x\not\in S$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
It's also (and more commonly, at least in my experience) denoted by $\chi_S$.

Comment: You are correct that it is more commonly referred to as $\chi_S$ (and in those contexts called the "characteristic function").  However IMHO it's a very good thing that the $\textbf{1}_S$ notation is gaining popularity, as I find it much more intuitive and easier on the eyes.

Comment: @BenW: what's unintuitive about using the Greek for "ch" as the symbol for the characteristic function? My first reading of $\mathbf{1}_S$ would be the identity function on $S$ and I had to do a double take and think about the OP's equation to see that $\chi_S$ was intended. If you don't like $\chi_S$, wouldn't $\mathbf{I}_S$ be better?

Comment: @RobArthan it's a subjective thing I guess, but I have found that reading papers with $\textbf{1}_S$ is simply easier than with $\chi_S$.  Not sure why that is, but that is what I have found.

Comment: @BenW: fair enough: each to their own $\ddot{\smile}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's the indicator function.
$$
\textbf{1}_A(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1&\text{ if }x\in A\\0&\text{ if }x\notin A\end{array}\right.
$$